# How to make a Tooltip display dynamic based on a parameter value?

Tags: dynamic, manipulate, tooltip

If k=3, then I would like the following to say "Sine Curve, k=3" when you hover over the output of the `Tooltip` command:

```
Tooltip[Sin[k*x], "Sine Curve, k=", TooltipStyle -> FontSize -> 16]
```

I have made a number of attempts, using pure functions and substitutions, but none delivered the output I want.  The ultimate goal is to put this into a `Manipulate` where `k` is a user selectable value and the `Sin[k x]` function is plotted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String manipulation like in [jVincent's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16784/34) is nice, but I normally prefer to combine these types of elements using `Row`:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Tooltip[Sin[k x], Row[{"Sine Curve, k=", k}]], {x, 0, 4 Pi}], 
      {k, 1, 5}]
```

For more complicated objects, it just normally ends up being neater. Maybe my preference comes from having to work with `RowBox` and `MakeExpression` too much...
*Aside:* 
I would also use `"\[VeryThinSpace]\[LongEqual]\[VeryThinSpace]"` instead of just `"="`,
it looks nicer:
[image: example]
and in Mathematica, "=" is normally associated with [Set](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html).

Comment: Thank you, I do like the way this looks.  Especially when you are presenting larger fonts on a projector screen!

Answer (score 4):

You can insert the value into the tooltip using `ToString`:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Tooltip[Sin[k x], "Sine Curve, k=" <> ToString[k]], {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}],
 {k, 1, 5}]
```

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for, Thank you very much!